# Having trouble with microsoft query syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

I wrote a SQL query that works, but when I try to translate it to query on Microsoft query I'm running into a lot of problems syntactically.

This is the query I wrote originally:

```
select
    sum(PJC_FCTR_VL) 
from
   (select 
        max(PJC_FCTR_VL) 
    from 
        (select
             R_CATEGORY_70075, 
             PRDC_KEY
        from PRDC_DIM 
        where R_CATEGORY_70075 like '%RAMEN%')sub, 
        HS_PNLS_PJC_SBST_20150404 t1, 
        HSHLD_DIM t2, 
        HS_PRCH_SBST_20150404 t3
    where
        t1.PNLS_TYP_ID = 1
        and t3.HSHLD_ID = t2.HSHLD_ID
        and sub.PRDC_KEY = t3.PRDC_KEY
    group by 
        t1.HSHLD_ID) subqry
```

I tried to break this query down more to see where I'm messing up on the Microsoft query and this is what I've got:

```
select
    max(HS_PNLS_PJC_SBST_20150404.PJC_FCTR_VL) 
from 
    {
       PRDC_DIM.R_CATEGORY_70075, PRDC_DIM.PRDC_KEY
    FROM AODR2QPNLSFWPR.ADMIN.PRDC_DIM PRDC_DIM
    WHERE (PRDC_DIM.R_CATEGORY_70075 Like '%RAMEN%')} HS_PNLS_PJC_SBST_20150404
```

I end up getting an error that says "expected OJ after {" even though I'm not really doing an outer join. I was wondering if someone could help me edit the SQL so that it would satisfy the Microsoft syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like.....

```
select  sum(Max_PJC_FCTR_VL) 
from
( select t1.HSHLD_ID,  max(PJC_FCTR_VL) AS Max_PJC_FCTR_VL --<-- use two part name here
  from ( select R_CATEGORY_70075, 
                PRDC_KEY
        from    PRDC_DIM 
        where R_CATEGORY_70075 like '%RAMEN%'
     )sub
      INNER JOIN HS_PRCH_SBST_20150404 t3       ON  sub.PRDC_KEY = t3.PRDC_KEY
      INNER JOIN HSHLD_DIM t2                   ON t3.HSHLD_ID = t2.HSHLD_ID
      INNER JOIN HS_PNLS_PJC_SBST_20150404 t1   ON t1.HSHLD_ID = t2.HSHLD_ID  --<-- only guessing here
                                               AND t1.PNLS_TYP_ID = 1
group by t1.HSHLD_ID
) subqry
```